# Looking for a waterproof SPI temperature sensor

Tags: arduino-mega, sensors, i2c, spi, temperature-sensor

In my current project I'm using a DS18B20, which seems to be the only temperature sensor to show up when googling for waterproof temperature sensor for an arduino.

The sensor itself is fine, however, I'm outputting the sensor's data to a SPI screen, and whenever the sensor is called to read data I believe the SPI communication is interrupted because of 1-Wire, and you can see a white flicker on the screen. The background LED is flashing more brightly for one frame. It's almost unnoticeable, but it bothers me.

I'm not using delays, and I'm not redrawing unnecessary elements on the screen again. Only dynamic elements are refreshed when they need to, static elements are only drawn once on the screen. The sensor is called every 5 seconds with a comparison:

```
if(currentTime - lastTimeQueried >= delay){
    lastTimeQueried = currentTime;
    temperature = new temperature;
    return temperature;
} else {
    return temperature;
}
```

I also tried a function where I'm constantly calling the sensor and only drawing on the screen if there's a change in temperature, but then the screen is flickering all the time. Thus I conclude that the flickering is caused by the actual calling of the sensor, and not from redrawing anything on the screen.

So I'm wondering if there's an alternative to the DS18B20 that communicates via SPI, and that I can use in an aquarium, so I don't have to use both protocols in my project.

Edit:

As requested some more of my code and wiring:

The screen is wired to the ICSP headers on my Arduino Mega 2560 and power is supplied via 5V on a powersupply that is connected to my breadboard.

The DS18B20 is wired to pin 29 on the Arduino and is also supplied with power via 5V on the same powersupply.

```
//TFT SPI
#define TFT_DC 9
#define TFT_CS 10
Adafruit_ILI9341 tft = Adafruit_ILI9341(TFT_CS, TFT_DC);

//SD Card Reader SPI
//#define SD_CS 4

//Touchscreen I2C
UTouch  myTouch(5, 8, 6, 7, 2);  //(T_CLK, T_CS, T_DIN, T_DOUT, T_IRQ) 

#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 29
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);
```

Here are some more variables that I have defined to help with using the sensor:

```
//Temperature measurement
unsigned long lastTempMeasure;  //Holds last unix timestamp temperature was measured at
char tempMeasureDelay = 5;      //Call temperature every 5 seconds
float sensorTemp;               //Holds measured temperature
```

In my loop I then use this function:

```
tft.print(temperatureCall());
```

and then:

```
float temperatureCall(){
  //get unix time for right now
  unsigned long currentUnix = now();

  //if 5 seconds passed since last poll, ask for new temperature, else return old measurement
  if(currentUnix - lastTempMeasure >= tempMeasureDelay){
    lastTempMeasure = currentUnix; //save last polling time

    sensors.requestTemperatures();    
    sensorTemp = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);

    return sensorTemp;
  } else {
    return sensorTemp;
  }
}
```

As I said, the flicker only occurs when these two are used every 5 seconds:

```
sensors.requestTemperatures();    
sensorTemp = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
```

Edit 2:

Pic of wiring:

[image: wiring]

Comment: Can you share your wiring including LCD display over SPI and DS18B20 and some more of your code?

Comment: @Sener I have updated my post

Comment: It sounds more like a power issue rather than a communication issue. How are you powering the backlight for the display?

Comment: Thanks for the details, seeing big picture helps most of the time.
I consider, SPI pins are not shared with some other SPI device.
So, the sensor is on one of the digital pins which is also fine. But, since the onewire is using bit-banging, trying some other pins for the sensor would be wise.
Besides this, the backlight led is not obvious. I think it is directly connected to 5V, isn't it? I recommend measuring voltage and the current board draws. If they fluctuates (voltages drops) or making a sudden move than we can take it from there.

Comment: What I have also thought of that it might indeed be a powering issue since the sensor is using a pullup resistor on the data line which is connected to 5V.

@Majenko the backlight LED is powered by the powersupply via 5V.

I will update my post with a picture of the wiring

Comment: @Sener why would it be wise to try a different pin for the sensor? What other pin would you recommend?

Comment: It really looks like sudden voltage drop or lack of current (tiny) when the sensor is active.for reading. But, datasheet says it is not dramatic, 1mA to 4mA. 
But, apart from this, what I say that, I have those LCD's running on one of my products are not rock solid. In a batch, some of their backlight are bright some faded, some flickering.

Comment: Trying different pin is always a case I follow when debugging some issues in order to eliminate inconsistent design on some gates particularly clone components. You never know.

Comment: Hm, definitely food for thought. Will look more into this. Unfortunately I can't really measure any voltage drop with my multimeter which just shows mostly constant values on the backlight. Definitely no drops or peaks every 5 seconds.

This project might become a product, but at that stage I will be working together with a friend who is an electrician to help me with this, so he might know more.

Thanks for sharing your knowledge guys, this was really driving me a little nuts, knowing what's behind it or at least pushing me into the right direction definitely eased my mind.

Comment: Any time. A last note, you may try to place a 10uF Electrolytic on your power rail between GND and 5V. This can buffer (buy) some time when power is affected during sensor reading. Good luck with your project.

Comment: The 1-wire protocol uses specific timing. To do that, the OneWire library turns off the interrupts temporarily to create that signal. You can test that by turning off the interrupts for some time to see what will happen. Is there really no time for the OneWire library without disturbing the display? Perhaps the sketch needs to be fixed. There are good i2c temperature sensors. You can make them waterproof with food-safe materials. The best solution might be to replace the display and use a smart display with serial communication.

Comment: @Jot there is a clock on the display that also shows seconds. Maybe I can jerry-rig something in, but then it may slow down the entire sketch.

Comment: @Sener I have added a capacitor to my wiring. Another interesting observation I have made is that if I connect ground from my rail to the ground of my arduino, the screen turns completely white after the sketch ran for 5 seconds, presumably because it then calls the temperature of the sensor..

When I remove the capacitor, the same thing happens, but only after 10 or 15 seconds.

Comment: What you are saying reminds me my another experience with running two SPI's together. If you don't place resistors (4k7) serially connected to MOSI and SCK pins, they were effecting each others and my TFT 2.2'' display was going white. If so, what @jot says may be quite relevant to your issue.
You may be also try another version of 1-wire libraries.
Let's say [1-wire library](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/OneWire)

Comment: @Sener I already used 1k resistors on every data line. I tried 5k resistors, but then I couldn't keep the display running. It would display one frame and then do weird stuff. Tried with 2k resistors too which seems to have improved the issue a little. Unfortunately I don't have 4.7k resistors on hand...I should really expand from the parts that I have available from my tutorial kit.

Answer (score 1):

There is a delay in the DallasTemperature `requestTemperatures()` function - it blocks until the temperature conversion is complete unless you have previously called `setWaitForConversion(FALSE)`. If you did that, you would still have to wait for the conversion but you can do it an a non-blocking manner, and I don't see that happening in your code.

Comment: Thank you.

Is this something I need to call once in the setup? Or every time I am polling temperature from the sensor?

Comment: Looking at this DS18b20 library, the flag does *not* appear to get changed except by an external call, so setting it once should be sufficient. [Sorry for my typo in the original reply].